# Output CSS class according to selected option in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, form-api

I am using Drupal 6. I have this form in a file comment_field.module:

```
function comment_fields_example_comment_fields_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['all'] = array(
    'feeling' => array(
      '#title' => t('Come giudichi il servizio di Erremmeservice?'),
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#default_value' => 'neutral',
      '#options' => array(
        'good' => t('Positivo'),
        'neutral' => t('Medio'),
        'bad' => t('Negativo'),
      ),
    ),  
  );
}
```

And I have this code in file comment.tpl.php of my theme:

```
<?php if (!empty($comment_fields_feeling)) :?>
      <p>Giudico il servizio offerto da erremmeservice : <?php print $comment_fields_feeling ?>.</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now all work perfectly but I should have this:

- If user check option 'Positivo' the result printed have color green (or simply a class...)
- If user check option 'Medio' the result printed have color yellow (or simply a class...)
- If user check option 'Negativo' the result printed have color red (or simply a class...)

Comment: Do you want to add a CSS class to your `<p>` tag according to the value of `$comment_fields_feeling`?

Comment: Arent you getting the details attached with this comment in the `$content` variable in `comment.tpl.php` file? If yes and if I understand correctly, you can modify the display based on the value you get.

Comment: yes Ronni i want this... The script work perfectly but print a simple test without color...

Answer (score 0):

I have solved. It was simple... i have used this 3 scripts:

```
<?php  
if ( $comment_fields_feeling == "Positivo" ) {
    echo "il tuo giudizio è : <span style='color:green;'>Positivo!</span><br />";
}
else {echo "";}
      ?>
       <?php  
if ( $comment_fields_feeling == "Medio" ) {
    echo "il tuo giudizio è : <span style='color:yellow;'>Medio!</span><br />";
}
else {echo "";}
      ?>
      <?php  
if ( $comment_fields_feeling == "Negativo" ) {
    echo "il tuo giudizio è : <span style='color:red;'>Negativo!</span><br />";
}
else {echo "";}
      ?>
```